# html table render differently between firefox and google chrome browser

Tags: html, firefox, google-chrome, rendering

The code below render differently between firefox and google chrome (opera and safari render similar to google chrome)

I am not sure what is the cause of it, but I would prefer the firefox rendering, because the parent node of the tree structure spread from the middle rather than top.

Could you point out what I have done wrong here?

Many Thanks & Kind Regards

### Andy

The code is located
https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1OAsOb-tV29KsNfSQXmgAdvv_2Fac_H8dVm0ktoMT8a8

To see a preview http://jsbin.com/ufamo5/edit

Comment: Could you post your code in the question? Not everyone is allowed access to Google Docs :(

Comment: @Town I made a link to a jsbin.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite tell, but it's probably due to a tag closed improperly, and being interpreted slightly differently by the html parser in Firefox and Chrome